# Can I hide the bubble when showing a Google map lazily using an iframe?

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google Maps in a lazy fashion (not using their API).

```
<iframe height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="335" src="http://maps.google.com.au/maps?f=q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=23+Project+Avenue, Noosaville, 4566, Queensland, Australia&amp;output=embed" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
```

Here, I just echo the `urlencode()` of the address and let Google Maps figure it all out.

[image: Google Map]

[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/STTzp/)

I was wondering if there was any GET param I can use to stop the automatic bubble from appearing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI the Google Maps url format is documented here: http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters
take a look at the Info Window parameters http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters#Info_Windows

Comment: Well, [they provided the embed code](http://i.imgur.com/r6xqg.png), so I thought it would be OK

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez Nope, but it did sometimes :S